# How many days from the list were in given period [R]

Tags: r

I’d like to count using R, how many days of given list:

```
 2020-10-01
 2020-10-03
 2020-10-07
 2020-10-08
 2020-10-09
 2020-10-10
 2020-10-14
 2020-10-17
 2020-10-21
 2020-10-22
 2020-10-27
 2020-10-29
 2020-10-30
```

Were in given period from start to end:

```
  id       start         end
   1    2020-10-05   2020-10-30
   2    2020-10-06   2020-10-29
   3    2020-10-10   2020-10-12
```

And the result should be for example:

```
  id     number of days
  1             5   
  2            18
  3            12
```

Comment: according to your definition, the number of days should be 11, 10 and 1. Why do you have 5, 18 and 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a `tidyverse` approch with `lubridate` and `dplyr`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 count(id, start, end, 
       wt = days %within% interval(start, end), 
       name = "number_of_days")

#>      id start      end        number_of_days
#> 1     1 2020-10-05 2020-10-30             11
#> 2     2 2020-10-06 2020-10-29             10
#> 3     3 2020-10-10 2020-10-12              1
```

For each row, count the number of `days` within the interval of `start` and `end` (extremes included).

(If you don't want to see `start` and `end` just remove them from the first line of `count`)

---

Where:

```
days <- c("2020-10-01",
          "2020-10-03",
          "2020-10-07",
          "2020-10-08",
          "2020-10-09",
          "2020-10-10",
          "2020-10-14",
          "2020-10-17",
          "2020-10-21",
          "2020-10-22",
          "2020-10-27",
          "2020-10-29",
          "2020-10-30")


df <- read.table(text = "  id       start         end
   1    2020-10-05   2020-10-30
   2    2020-10-06   2020-10-29
   3    2020-10-10   2020-10-12", header = TRUE)


days <- as.Date(days)
df$start <- as.Date(df$start)
df$end   <- as.Date(df$end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the dates are of date class you can use `mapply` :

```
df2$num_days <- mapply(function(x, y) sum(df1$dates >= x & df1$dates <= y), df2$start, df2$end)
```